# How can tin whiskers be produced?

Tags: crystals, chirality

How can tin [whiskers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whisker_(metallurgy)) be produced in an easy way as fast as possible without needing temperatures above 100 °C and in atmospheric pressure?

Metal whiskers grow from bottom and up. It is not a form of deposit on the top from gaseous metals, which some say. The following videos show growth from the bottom and interior.

> https://web.calce.umd.edu/tin-whiskers/whisker_movie_19min.html